# How to get md5 of byte array in Node JS?

Tags: java, node.js

I have a JAVA piece of code as following :

```
public static String base64AndMD5(byte[] bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.reset();
    md.update(bytes);
    byte[] md5Result = md.digest();
    String base64Result = Base64.encodeBase64String(md5Result);
    return base64Result.length() > 24 ? base64Result.substring(0, 23) : base64Result;
}
```

I have zero experience with java and most of time work on Node JS. This function expects a byte array and then finds md5 of it and then base64 encodes. I was trying to implement it in NodeJs in the following way:

```
byteArray = [123, 10, 32, 32, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 95, 105, 100, 34, 58, 32, 34, 49, 52, 55, 48, 57, 53, 57, 54, 48, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 105, 110, 99, 111, 100, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 108, 97, 116, 34, 58, 32, 34, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 108, 111, 110, 103, 34, 58, 34, 34, 10, 32, 32, 32, 125, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 103, 97, 95, 105, 100, 34, 32, 58, 32, 34, 49, 50, 51, 34, 10, 32, 32, 125, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 99, 104, 97, 110, 110, 101, 108, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 110, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 97, 110, 100, 114, 111, 105, 100, 97, 112, 112, 34, 10, 32, 32, 125, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 99, 117, 115, 116, 111, 109, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 34, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 95, 112, 97, 103, 101, 34, 32, 58, 32, 34, 104, 111, 109, 101, 112, 97, 103, 101, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 50, 48, 49, 56, 57, 52, 55, 57, 57, 34, 10, 32, 32, 125, 10, 125];

let md5OfByteArray = crypto.createHash('md5').update(byteArray).digest("hex");
```

But it returns an error that byteArray should be a string or buffer. Now when I push execute java function with above byte array it returns, `hKJQcQlv5e1RB5WyDZX3AA==`. Can someone explain what these java functions are doing and how can we do the same in nodejs?

Comment: Java encodes the `byte` array in Base64. So in node you'd have to decode this base64 string into probably an `ArrayBuffer`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a buffer based on your bytes array. Then you can hash and encode to base64

```
function base64AndMD5(bytesArray) {

  const buf = Buffer.from(bytesArray); // bytesArray = [123, 10, 32, 32, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 95, 105, 100, 34, 58, 32, 34, 49, 52, 55, 48, 57, 53, 57, 54, 48, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 105, 110, 99, 111, 100, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 108, 97, 116, 34, 58, 32, 34, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 108, 111, 110, 103, 34, 58, 34, 34, 10, 32, 32, 32, 125, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 103, 97, 95, 105, 100, 34, 32, 58, 32, 34, 49, 50, 51, 34, 10, 32, 32, 125, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 99, 104, 97, 110, 110, 101, 108, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 110, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 97, 110, 100, 114, 111, 105, 100, 97, 112, 112, 34, 10, 32, 32, 125, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 99, 117, 115, 116, 111, 109, 34, 58, 32, 123, 10, 32, 32, 32, 34, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 95, 112, 97, 103, 101, 34, 32, 58, 32, 34, 104, 111, 109, 101, 112, 97, 103, 101, 34, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 50, 48, 49, 56, 57, 52, 55, 57, 57, 34, 10, 32, 32, 125, 10, 125]

  const hashed = crypto
                       .createHash('md5')
                       .update(buf)
                       .digest("base64"); // hKJQcQlv5e1RB5WyDZX3AA==

  return hashed.length > 24 ? hashed.slice(0, 23) : hashed;
  // this is weird, I would expect hashed.length >= 24 rather than > but anyways it respects your java code.
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it in plain JS?

Comment: you mean in the browser without Node libs?

Comment: Yes. I'm okay using libs via CDN.